# How do I quickly show/hide the desktop?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I want to be able to hide all the windows quickly.

How can i make an icon or entering which command will help me to hide all of the opened windows and show me a desktop?

Comment: `Ctrl-Win-D` is the keyboard shortcut to show/hide the desktop.

Comment: In `KDE` it is `Glogal Keyboard Shortcuts` -> `KWin` -> `Show Desktop` - which actually toggles show desktop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you hold down the 'super' key, which on my keyboard is the Windows key, for a second you can see a list of keyboard shortcuts pop up.

One of them is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all open windows, i.e. to go to the desktop.

Due to the debate below, I feel compelled to amend my answer to note that on some systems, the shortcut may be <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: In mine its ctrl + super + D, not ctrl + alt + D

Comment: @StephenMartin , yes, that's what it is on mine too, and what my answer originally said. I don't know why Benjamin edited it. Editing it back to the original, and correct, answer.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+D in 12.04

Comment: @darryn.ten : 12.04 is what I have as well, but the shortcut is, on my system, ctrl+super+D

Comment: Interesting that there is a difference..

Answer (score 0):

official documentation:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts

how to personalize the key combination:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1735542