# How can I hide all windows and show the desktop quickly?

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts, docky

I know there are supposed to be several ways to do this, but I will explain why they don't work for me.

1. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> both result in this [bug.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645610/super-d-hides-copy-dialog-forever-in-15-04) So does the "Show Desktop" button in the Unity launcher and the "Show Desktop" that appears in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> app switcher. I'm guessing that all four execute the same command(s).
2. I use `Docky`. But the Docky docklet "Show Desktop" does not work due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/1307399).
3. I don't use the Unity launcher (I hide it) but I guess, as a last resort, I wouldn't be uninterested in ways that involve it. I read about something called "My Unity," but I couldn't find out how to install it. Anyhow, I am primarily interested in a way that uses a keyboard shortcut or `Docky`.

So there are three really nice ways to hide all windows and show the desktop that, unfortunately, don't work at the moment.

In this question I am asking for:

1. A way to solve one or more of these bugs.
2. More ways to accomplish the same thing, without the bugs. I prefer ways that don't depend on the Unity launcher, but I'd still like to hear about those that do.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit.

Comment: How about `Ctlr + Super + D` as depicted in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154023/how-do-i-quickly-show-hide-the-desktop

Comment: @Parto are you suggesting that may not cause the same bug that `Super + D` causes?

Comment: I don't think it will. Try it out and tell me.

Comment: If you don't mind using workspaces, you could also just use CTRL+ALT+ARROW to switch to an empty workspace where you would see the desktop as well.

Comment: @Parto I just tested it, and unfortunately, the two shortcuts cause exactly the same bug. By the way, what is the difference between `Super+D` and `Super+Ctrl+D`?

Comment: @ByteCommander This solution is pretty cool, worthy of being an answer, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple workspaces and switch to a new empty workspace instead of minimizing all windows on the current one to see the desktop.

To enable workspaces, open **System Settings → Appearance**, switch to the **Behaviour** tab and tick the **Enable workspaces** checkbox.

Then you have 4 workspaces (2x2) between which you can switch using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow ↑←↓→</kbd>.

To move the focused window on a different workspace, you can select **Move to workspace up/left/down/right** or **Move to another workspace** from the window title bar's context menu, or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow ↑←↓→</kbd>.

Comment: But if I open something from the desktop then, it will then be in the new workspace, right?

Comment: @Fiksdal Yes, each workspace can have open windows. Not sure, but there should be a command to move all windows back to workspace 1 at once...

Comment: And what is that command?

Comment: I am not sure. You could ask that as new question or take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/q/470324/367990 but it's not very helpful for Unity Desktop...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as good as Byte Commander's solution, but there's another workaround : when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> you see list of windows to switch to , among which there is "Show Desktop" option. If you hover mouse to it while still holding the key combination and click, it will show the desktop

Comment: Do you know whether this uses the same command as `Super+D` and the shortcut in the Unity Launcher? If yes, isn't is likely to result in the same bug that is referred to in OP? I'll test it the next time I have access to an Ubuntu system.

Comment: @Fiksdal I would assume it's the same action/command that is being called. Try it out, see if it helps. It's hard to say what your issue is related to, so I would try out variety of methods. There probably is a `dbus` command for  that but i haven't found one yet

Comment: Will try it, just need to get back to the Ubuntu machine I manage first. It belongs to someone else.

Comment: Sorry about the long delay, but I can confirm, that this results in the same bug as described in OP. Will update OP.