# Window stuck in workspace

Tags: unity, workspaces

So, I was playing around with the workspace ByteCommander suggested and I was trying to move a window down to the bottom left workspace and it got stuck

[How can I hide all windows and show the desktop quickly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752148/how-can-i-hide-all-windows-and-show-the-desktop-quickly)

The top bar that you use the mouse to move the window is stuck right in between the top left and bottom left workspace so I cannot move it at all

Also I can't close it or kill it, because [I'm folding,](http://folding.stanford.edu/) I need to exit it properly without losing my folds

Any help is greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: Move the window with the mouse while pressing ALT.

Comment: I can't get to the window @Jos

Comment: are you still having this issue ?

Comment: not as  often no, I've had it like 2 since we last talked but they went away by them selves after like 2 minutes so it hasn't really been that bad

Comment: @Serg   I forgot to tag you sorry